# wants to call one web service in a thread within time limit to execute in java

Tags: java, multithreading

any example of code

wants to call one web service  in a thread and need to set a time limit to execute that thread
and need to return the value successful and failed  ids 
 like t.start(); and t.stop(); within time

Answer (score 2):

```
Future<T> result = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().submit(
    new Callable<T>() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //perform action here
            while(!Thread.interrupted()){
                //do next stage of calculation
            }
        }
    });
T value = result.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //for example wait 10 seconds
if(value == null) {
    //process is not finished
    result.cancel(true);    //interrupt task
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Web service calls are atomic operations and it will not return partial results unless it is designed to do so. For example a web service which takes in a request and starts processing, and a second service call interrupts the operation and asks for partial results.